# How to display an image in the column of jqgrid

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller, jqgrid

I want to display a image in the column of jqgrid for all data I get from   '/Index/CaseBatchDetailList'. i have my jquery like,

```
 $(function () {
var outerwidth = $('#TableCaseDtlsView').width();
$("#CaseBatchDetailList").jqGrid({
    url: '/Index/CaseBatchDetailList',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ["Serial Number", "Denomination", "Note Image", "Back Image"],
    colModel: [
                    { name: "serialno", sortable: true, width: "120px", align: "center" },
                    { name: "denomination", sortable: true, width: "120px", align: "left" },
                    {
                        name: "frontimageurl", sortable: false, width: "290px", align: "center", fixed: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return "<img src = /F:/MCP_Images/635101007551068098_324.jpg>";
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "backimageurl", sortable: false, width: "290px", align: "center", fixed: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return "<img src = /F:/MCP_Images/635101007551068098_324.jpg>";
                        }
                    }
    ],
 ...
});
```

i just tried with the example for img src. I need to display the different images in different columns. As iam the beginner i dont know how to manipulate this.Kindly tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: You should not put a `file://` path. instead you can put your images in the folder of your project and refer them relatively.

Comment: i just tried with the example. Actully i need to display the list of images returned from '/Index/CaseBatchDetailList'

Comment: could you post your list in your question too.

Answer (score 1):

As i saw your comment that you are having the image source in the list, then within your formatter you can do this:

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
    return "<img src='"+cellvalue+"'>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.It works but it doesn't display the image instead display small icon with "X" symbol.